# Why doesn't the Hydrogen atom, as described by the Dirac equation, collapse?

Tags: schroedinger-equation, quantum-spin, dirac-equation, variational-principle

In Griffiths quantum mechanics, it's noted that the exact energies for the Dirac equation, involving fine structure, are

$$E_{nj} = mc^2 \left\{ \left[1 + \left(\frac{\alpha}{n-(j+1/2)+\sqrt{(j+1/2)^2 - \alpha^2}}               \right)^2 \right]^{-1/2} - 1 \right\}$$

However, to me this is strange: There is something catastrophic that happens when considering the non-relativistic Schrodinger equation with spin-orbit coupling, [as noted in a previous question of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/703874): one can find a variational state with energy unbounded below!

I'll illustrate this with a slightly different choice of variational wavefunction: $|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{24}} \beta^{5/2} r e^{-\beta r} |l=1, j=1/2, m_j=1/2 \rangle \equiv \frac{1}{\sqrt{24}}\beta^{5/2} r e^{-\beta r} \left( \sqrt{2/3} Y^1_1 |\downarrow\rangle - \sqrt{1/3} Y^1_0 |\uparrow\rangle\right) $.

The spin-orbit coupling takes the form of $c \frac{(\vec{S} \cdot \vec{L})}{r^3}$, and the spin and orbit parts of the wavefunction above are such that the spin-orbit coupling is negative. The expectation of the spin-orbit piece is hence $\propto - \beta^{3}$. The other terms in the hydrogen atom are subleading when $\beta \rightarrow \infty$, and so we see this state has energy unbounded below in $\beta$.

---

However, we see that the exact result for the Dirac equation seems fine. What in the Dirac equation remedies this problem in the non-relativistic theory and prevents this collapse? In particular, what gives an appropriate energy barrier to prevent the energy from being bounded below?